# [JAVA]Recursively removing empty cell in minesweeper

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a minesweeper assignment right now. And I used recursion to implement the function that removes an empty area. However my program always runs into eroor. The error message states:
a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

And this is my code, I know it looks messy, apologize in advance. I would appreciate any help!

```
public void removeEmptyRegion(int x, int y){ //note: uses recursive decomposition
    if (x < 0 || x > width-1 || y < 0 || y > length-1) {
        return; // check for bounds
    }else if(tiles[y][x].getClicked()){ //first time activated this method
        //checks the tiles surround it
        removeEmptyRegion(x,y+1);//up
        removeEmptyRegion(x,y-1);//down
        removeEmptyRegion(x+1,y);//left
        removeEmptyRegion(x-1,y);//right
        removeEmptyRegion(x-1, y+1); //up-left
        removeEmptyRegion(x+1, y+1); //up-right
        removeEmptyRegion(x-1,y-1); //down-left
        removeEmptyRegion(x+1,y-1); //down-right
    }
    else if(!(tiles[y][x].getValue() == -1) && tiles[y][x].getClicked() == false ) { 
        //check: -1 indicates it is a bomb
        if(tiles[y][x].getValue() == 0) {
            tiles[y][x].clickTile();
            //chain reaction
            removeEmptyRegion(x,y+1);//up
            removeEmptyRegion(x,y-1);//down
            removeEmptyRegion(x+1,y);//left
            removeEmptyRegion(x-1,y);//right
            removeEmptyRegion(x-1, y+1); //up-left
            removeEmptyRegion(x+1, y+1); //up-right
            removeEmptyRegion(x-1,y-1); //down-left
            removeEmptyRegion(x+1,y-1); //down-right
            return;
        }else { //stops if the tile is a numbered tile
            tiles[y][x].clickTile();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow in a recursive algorithm is usually a sign that you `return` condition isn't being met. I'd look into that.

Comment: try to run this method alone. for instance from public static void main method with some tiles array pooulated

Comment: and although add a println to check width and length variable values

Comment: Also look to see if the same space is being processed multiple times.  For instance if you are on space x,y and then process x, y+1, will that space in turn process x,y again?

Comment: Invoking removeEmptyRegion(x,y) invokes removeEmptyRegion(x,y+1) which invokes removeEmptyRegion(x,y-1).  The first and last invocation refer to the same value of y so the recursion never ends.  Same with the x.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that people with reputation 1-5 just asking a question a waiting for correct complete code. don't comment, don't accept right answers etc.)))

Comment: Thank you everyone, I think I know where the root is XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check each possible direction from each tile recursively.
Say your code is at 0,0 and now it checks the tile above. Now it's at 0,1. Then, from 0,1 your code checks a few directions, including down. Now it's back at 0,0. This repeats infinitely, causing a stack overflow.

I suggest using something called memoization.

Create a `boolean[][]` with the same dimensions as your minesweeper grid. When you check a square, mark `boolean[y][x]=true`.

At the top of your method where you check if you are out of bounds, use `if (boolean[y][x])` to check if you've already checked there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I know to fix this right now!